# { or ; expected error how can i solve this issue

Tags: c#

```
public int Room_No
        {
            get => room_no;
            set
            {
                if (this.room_no >= 0)
                {
                    this.room_no = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Room Number can't be negative");
                }
            }
        }
```

the error here

```
 get => room_no;
```

when i try to solve this issue another issue appeared

Comment: Unrelated: I'd suggest to take the validation out of the Model. And especially not to intermingle UI into it. Then this can boil down to an Auto-Property and the problem goes away as a side-effect.

Comment: Also unrelated: I'd recommend to consider typical [C# naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names).

Comment: "the error here" - what error? you haven't told us what happened; as a tip - to get good answers, you should say **exactly** what happened, ideally copying/pasting the message; "when i try to solve this issue another issue appeared" - again: **what appeared?** we aren't psychic and we can't see your screen from here; @SomeBody has *probably* inferred the correct thing, but it would be much clearer if you'd told us what the problem *was*

Comment: ^^ We also usually assume a fairly recent set of tooling is in use if not otherwise stated. So if you are using an older C# version, it's probably good to mention that explicitly.

Comment: to expand on what @Fildor says: your *setter* should almost certainly not display a message-box; an *exception* would be fine: `if (room_no < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(...)` - and let the UI deal with UI issues

Comment: @MarcGravell While I agree, that more information would be better, the error message ___is___ in the title of the question.

Comment: @JeanotZubler not exactly what I'd call a full compiler output, but: fair enough for the first - does nothing to address "another issue appeared", though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda syntax for properties was introduced at C# 7. It looks as your compiler is configured to use an older C# version. You have two possibilities:

- Change your compiler's settings to use a newer C# version
- Use the older syntax for properties:

  ```
  public int Room_No
  {
       get { return room_no; }
       set
       {
           if (this.room_no >= 0)
           {
               this.room_no = value;
           }
           else
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Room Number can't be negative");
           }
       }
  }
  ```

Comment: ^^ This assumes, `room_no` is a private class field of type `int`, which is very probably the case, but not explicitly shown in the question. If it's not, you should clarify @Eslam